# Excel 2016 "Encrypt With Password" Option is Grayed Out

Tags: microsoft-excel, encryption, passwords

Although I have the open password, I cannot change it since the "Encrypt With Password" option is grayed out under File>Info>Protect Workbook, similar to image below.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the fix mentioned in your [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/password-protect-grayed-out/4e8d3936-a3a5-4126-9830-297a77d70ea0)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, but did not find the Security folder for office 16. Anyway, the Encrypt option is no longer grated out after reopening the file. Not sure what changed.

Comment: Sorry, removed link when embedding image, here it is....https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/password-protect-grayed-out/4e8d3936-a3a5-4126-9830-297a77d70ea0

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for.
I also encountered the same issue in Microsoft 365.
After a trial and error, I found it became available.
I first **Protected the Worksheet and Workbook** via the menu, **Review**.
Then, "**Encrypt with Password**" became available.
I also found that the passwords used for *Protecting the Sheet/Workbook* and *Encrypting the file* don't have to be the same.
I am sorry for I cannot take the screen-shots.